# Is the user and role information accessible using SQL? Where is the SHOW USERS data stored?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

From what I understand the command below when called from the `ACCOUNTADMIN` role

```
SHOW USERS;
```

shares this list. I am trying to obtain a list of every user and every role that user belongs in one select statement. Something like

```
select role, user from roles join users on roles.userid = users.userid.
```

I can then find out which roles have been granted access to which objects by joining that to the `SNOWFLAKE.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.OBJECT_PRIVILEGES` table.

I tried doing this in a stored procedure using a `SHOW USERS;` followed by a `RESULT_SCAN` command, but stored procedures do not allow the execution of a `SHOW USERS` command.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One recommendation was to use a javascript stored procedure that stores the results of "SHOW USERS;" from an amazing individual:

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SHOW_USERS_SP()
RETURNS VARIANT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$ 
    var return_rows = [];
 
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({
        sqlText: 'SHOW USERS'
    });
    
    var result = stmt.execute();
    while(result.next()) {
        return_rows.push([result.getColumnValue("name"), result.getColumnValue("display_name")])
    }
    
    return return_rows;
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

In a stored procedure EXECUTED AS OWNER (regardless of language) executing `SHOW USERS;` is not supported.  When EXECUTED AS CALLER it depends on if you have granted usage on the procedure to the role making the call.

As an alternative, you can use a language like python to iterate over the list of users running SHOW GRANTS TO , and write the results out to a table.  You can do the same for each role with SHOW GRANTS TO .  From there you can use a recursive query to over your GRANTS_TO_ROLE table then join to your GRANTS_TO_USER table.